# Only First mat-form-field is Displayed Initially

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to make a simple page for people to enter the form data which uses materials module in angular. When trying to display multiple `mat-form-field`s, only the first one is displayed initially. Only when I click on one of the form field are the other ones displayed.

### File Layout:

```
-app
  |
  |-contactus(folder)
  |-app.component.html
  |-app.component.ts
  |-material.module.ts
  |-app.module.ts
```

### contactus.html:

```
<div class="back">
    <div class="title" style="margin: auto">
       <mat-card>
          <h2> CONTACT US IS UNDER CONSTRUCTION </h2>
       </mat-card>
    </div>
<form>
<mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Details"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Other"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
</div>
```

### contactus.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contactus',
  templateUrl: './contactus.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contactus.component.css']
})
export class ContactusComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

### app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { ContactusComponent } from './contactus/contactus.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContactusComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### material.module.ts

```
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatInputModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatButtonModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatInputModule
    ],
    exports: [
        MatButtonModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatInputModule
    ],
})

export class MaterialModule { }
```

Why is it not displaying the other form-fields initially?

Comment: there is node code in stackblitz add your correct url

Comment: The given stackblitz link doesn't have your code.

Comment: your link is incorrect! redirect to empty app on stackblizt.

Comment: @DavidR Sorry about that. How do I save it on stackblitz?

Comment: You'll see a `Save` button at the top bar.

Comment: Your code works fine. Your app setup must be the problem. Here it is on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d7wkq8.

Comment: @DavidR I tried saving it but nothing happens

Comment: @RohithS98 Guess you need to sign-in first, Better, try the `Share` option.

Comment: RohithS98 Please checkout @G.Tranter 's reply and his stackblitz code, which is working fine.

Comment: @DavidR I copied the share link and put it in the question initially. I also signed in with github

Comment: @DavidR I checked G Tanter's code. Most likely it is app setup issue. Which file should I post in the question?

Comment: @RohithS98 Your `contact us` module.

Comment: @RohithS98 Before that, Please try importing `MatInputModule` in your `app.module.ts` and see if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176165/discussion-between-david-r-and-rohiths98).

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me just now and the fix was to import `BrowserAnimationsModule` into app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 
...
@NgModule({
...
imports: [
BrowserAnimationsModule,...
]
...
```